# Value not written into HDFS file

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hdfs

I am trying to write a value into a file on the HDFS. Here is the code:

```
FileSystem fsys = FileSystem.get(new Configuration());
        String fileName = "/user/root/TestData/Parameter.txt";
        Path path = new Path(fileName);//(pathOfTestFile);    
//fstatus.getPath();
        FSDataOutputStream fos = null;
        try {
            fos = fsys.create(path);
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new 
OutputStreamWriter(fos));
        writer.write(iterations);
        writer.close();
        fos.close();
```

But, I see that the command hadoop fs -ls  shows a size of 4 , but when I do a hadoop fs -cat , the file doesn't show any contents.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming that iterations is an integer / short / byte. Either way the byte(s) representation of these values is zero or more 0x00 bytes, followed by a 0x04 byte. Neither 0x00 nor 0x04 are printable characters so it's to no surprise that `hadoop fs -cat` *shows* nothing in the output.

If you pipe the output to hexdump -C though, i imagine you'll see your output:

```
hadoop fs -cat /path/to/file | hexdump -C
```

**EDIT**

You're also using [BufferedWriter.write(int)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/BufferedWriter.html#write%28int%29) which actually writes out the int as a chaarcter. You should be using [FSDataOutputStream.writeInt(iterations)](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/DataOutputStream.html?is-external=true#writeInt%28int%29) (it actually is a method of DataOutputStream) and then [FSDataInputStream.readInt()](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/DataInputStream.html?is-external=true#readInt%28%29) to read it back again.

Comment: The iterations variable is actually an int. Once it is written, I am unable to read it. It gives numberformatexception. I am using reader.readInt() method. have tried other methods such as fsDataInputStreamObj.read() as well, all of them give exceptions.

Comment: ChrisWhite: why do you say the representation is the one you presented? it can be any representation of an integer/short/byte.
@AbhishekShivkumar: can you post the code for reading, too ? 
And try also fs -text, just to see if there is any difference !

Comment: @Razvan `fs -text` is similar to `fs -cat`, except it handles gzipped files and sequence files accordingly. In this case the OP is writing to a custom file, so -text and -cat will yield the same results

Comment: I agree they are similar. I was thinking there might've been a bug in the fs client :).